# Swift: Push Notifications not working after implementing Realm Database

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, realm

I have a small messaging app and user receives a push notification whenever the user gets a message. Recently I have implemented Realm Database for my app. I am storing all the data that comes from the server into the realm directly and displaying the data to the user from realm. So, after shifting to this way the push notifications are not working. But again if I download the current version that is in the AppStore, the notifications are working. Every message has a messageID and we are sending the messageID as one of the parameter in the push notifications. Can someone help me on what I can do to make the push notifications working again.

Comment: Can you share some related code?

Comment: @ystack which part of the code would you like to look at? 

I have used the standard push notifications code and I did not make any changes to the push notifications when adding Realm.

Comment: @ystack Can you please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Well, for getting push notifications to work, you not only need to configure the app correctly, you also need to configure the backend service & APNS linking correctly to get it to work.
You should try a methodical approach wherein you divide the entire feature implementation of push notifications into smaller sub-tasks like app side logic, backend configuration, Certificates & Provisioning Profile setup, etc. Try to examine each of these sub-task implementation & surely you would find the culprit. Since, you know the existing App Store version of the app is working,you have your task reduced